# Why my records became the same when i updated the Access database?

Tags: vb.net

Why does my DataGridView shown the same value that I entered in all the records(rows)? For example, I have 12 records in Access but when I try to update the record, the record is saved and changed but it is applied to all 12 records, not only the one that I select.

> MemberID   FirstName
>   0001    Tan Poh Yun
>   0002    Tan Poh Yun
>   0003    Tan Poh Yun
>   0004    Tan Poh Yun
>   0005    Tan Poh Yun
>   0006    Tan Poh Yun
>   0007    Tan Poh Yun
>   0008    Tan Poh Yun
>   0009    Tan Poh Yun
>   0010    Tan Poh Yun
>   0011    Tan Poh Yun
>   0012    Tan Poh Yun

here my code:

```
Private Sub bttnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bttnSave.Click
    i = MemberDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index

    searchmemberID.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(0, i).Value
    txtMemberName.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(1, i).Value
    MemberGender.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(2, i).Value
    MEMBERIC.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(3, i).Value
    MemberEmail.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(4, i).Value
    MemberHandphone.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(5, i).Value
    MemberAddress.Text = MemberDataGridView.Item(6, i).Value
    txtMemberName.Enabled = True
    MemberEmail.Enabled = True
    MemberHandphone.Enabled = True
    MemberAddress.Enabled = True
    Dim com As OleDbCommand
    com = New OleDbCommand("Update Member set [FirstName] =@sno", acsconn)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", txtMemberName.Text)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Record Saved")
```

Comment: the problem is in your code not in your data

Comment: i know, but i dunno how to solve it, can u help me?

Comment: You need a WHERE clause in your SQL - here is an online [SQL Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)  see also [Ask]

Comment: Because you missed where clause in SQL. Without where clause, it will update all records. example: Update UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you missed `where` clause in SQL. Without `where` clause, it will update all records. You can do it like:

```
  UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1 WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Comment: com = New OleDbCommand("Update Member set [FirstName] =@sno WHERE MemberID = '" & searchmemberID.Text & "", acsconn)

Comment: Please post your query here @Snowish

Comment: com = New OleDbCommand("Update Member set [FirstName] =@sno WHERE MemberID = '" & searchmemberID.Text & "", acsconn)

Comment: is memberID interger ?

Comment: are you sure member ID is not interger datatype

Comment: Dim sqlQuery as string = "Update Member set [FirstName] =@sno WHERE MemberID=" & searchmemberID.Text

Comment: i used this (Dim i As Integer) to membergridview

Comment: It is simple case of type mismatch, check my above two comments

Comment: (Data type mismatch in criteria expression), should i change the text to number in access?

Comment: see, if MemberID is interger, then you need to make sure you dont give single quotes in your query

Comment: I don;t know what exactly you doing, yeah, change it to integer

Comment: @Snowish Did you tried, query I wrote above in comments?

Comment: yup, i tried it,Data type mismatch in criteria expression shown, now i trying to change my access.thanks a lots

Comment: In your first query, if you keep memberid as text, you were missing closing quote, so in that query would be:   com = New OleDbCommand("Update Member set [FirstName] =@sno WHERE MemberID = '" & searchmemberID.Text & "'", acsconn)  ...use this if you don't change your access table

Comment: if work i will accept it as my answer.^^ i tried to use the query above , its worked but the record doesn't change , still remain the same record.

Comment: You are missing condition in where clause @Snowish, show me your table data, and tell me what you need to update on which criteria

Comment: how to give u?? here?

Comment: u used the query that u posted above

Comment: Please post your query here